# Set up a web filter to block even the root user?

Tags: linux, root, web-filtering

Is it possible to set up a web filter in Linux which even the root user will not be able to alter? I am the only user on my laptop, and I need root access to do things like install stuff, etc.

I want to block myself from certain domains by using a web filter, but any web filter has a config file which is accessible to root.

I'd rather not set up a hypervisor and just be root in a VM, it sounds like overkill... Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: If you are the only user on the laptop, why don't you set up a web filter and not just change it?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do in Linux that can't be un-done by `root`.  Your best hope is probably to set up a separate machine to be your web-proxy, and run the filter on that machine.